# Change permalink of post if it belongs to custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, taxonomy

My posts are all located at `/blog/post-name/`

I have a custom taxonomy called a 'Series'. The series can be accessed at `/blog/series-name` which shows all posts in that series.

What I would like to do is have all posts within the series have their URL changed to `/blog/series-name/post-name`, but all other posts just stay as `/blog/post-name`.

How can I do this in `functions.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the permalinks using the [the_permalink](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink) filter and add a rewrite rule using [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to redirect the new permalinks to the standard post link.

```
function mysite_modify_permalink($url) {
  global $post;
  //if taxonomy archive for Series get term
  $term = is_tax('Series')?get_query_var('term'):'';
  if(empty($term)) { //if no term was found
    //get all Series terms for current post
    $terms = get_the_terms($post, 'Series');
    //if terms were found, take first term found
    if(!empty($terms) && is_array($terms)) $term = $terms[0]->slug;
  }
  //if term was found return a modified permalink url
  //(replace last url segment starting from '/' with '/<term slug><last segment>')
  if(!empty($term)) return preg_replace('#/blog(/[^/]+/?)$#', '/blog/'.$term.'$1', $url);
  //else return original url
  else return $url;
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'mysite_modify_permalink');

function mysite_add_rewrule() {
  //get all Series terms
  $terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'Series'));
  //if terms were found, add a rewrite rule for urls containing one of them
  if(!empty($terms) && is_array($terms)) {
    foreach($terms as $key => $term) $terms[$key] = $term->slug;
    $terms = '(?:' . implode('|', $terms) . ')';
    add_rewrite_rule('^blog/'.$terms.'(/[^/]+/?)$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]', 'top');
  }
}
add_action('init', 'mysite_add_rewrule');
```

Comment: Hi, this works great for changing the permalinks, but when I click through to the post, the URL does not include the taxonomy slug. It's like a redirect happened but I don't know where from.

Comment: oh perhaps because i redirected to blog/post, and another translation of the url happens. I'm changing it.

Comment: let me know if this works, i changed just the line with add_rewrite_rule

Comment: made another change in the line before that, added `?:`

Comment: Thanks, it didn't make a difference though. I have tried everything under the sun but Wordpress just definitely wants to redirect all post URLs to `/blog/post-name`. So if I use your permalink function the link will correctly be `/blog/series-name/post-name` but when I click through it will remove the `/series-name` part. I have no idea where that redirect is coming from and WP is so hard to debug. Note that it doesn't give a 404 however, so there's definitely a redirect happening.

Comment: hmm, try changing top to bottom

Comment: Yeah I tried everything, I've spent about 12 hours or more trying to solve this issue.

Comment: maybe something is different in .htaccess?

Comment: i have added index.php in the redirect, maybe that will fix it

Comment: yw :) just sorry i didn't spot it earlier :(